# replace value in N column in bash

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a below sample

```
a12,b12122,c12,d12
a13,887988,c13,d13
a14,b14121,c79,d13
```

I want to change only ***79*** to ***hh*** only if come in column 2.

when I do

```
awk -F, '$2~"79"' myfile | sed 's/79/hh/g' > temp && mv  temp myfile
```

It gives me 2nd row and 1st and 3rd gone.

what should I replace in my code so  so it only replace only ***79*** in the value ***887988*** to ***hh***

I check in other forum it can be done something like below code, but I guess I am doing some code error

```
$ awk '{gsub("79","hh",$2)}1' myfile 

a12,b112122,c12,d12
a13,887988,c13,d13
a14,b14121,c79,d13
```

**[EDIT]**
Thanks to below work

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 ~ /79/ { sub(/79/, "hh", $2) }1' file
```

but when i try to remove comma... in new sample

My sample is

```
cat > myfile
"a12","b112122","c12,d12"
a13,887988,c13,d13
a14,b14121,c79,d13
```

when I try to remove **"** from column 2 by

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 ~ /"/ { sub(/"/, "", $2) }1' myfile 
"a12",b112122","c12,d12"
a13,887988,c13,d13
a14,b14121,c79,d13
```

It only remove only 1 comma, instead of **b112122** i am getting **b112122"**

What I am doing wrong?

**I have part 2 of my code.**

How can I grep those which start with ***b1*** in column ***2*** only and length must be ***6***

if I do

```
cat myfile | grep -x '.\{6\}'  | grep "^[b1]"
```

It give me a blank result.

what would be the awk (like like ***$2 ~ /b1/*** ) for only those start with b1 and length will be 6

Comment: What if the value in `$2=="797979"`, replace all instances? Also, a lot of `88` and `hh` for 2019 (+1)...

Comment: @JamesBrown its a sample data, actual file I know well, I just way to learn the path for how I am gonna do that... :))

Comment: @WDC: Extended questions are not generally recommended, you need to ask separate questions

Comment: @WDC: I've answered your extended question in the answer now

Comment: @Inian perfect work for me, all i need to know whats wrong with "

Comment: @Inian accept mean "up" a sign or "check" sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine the parts for identifying the row element containing `79` and doing a replacement on it using `sub()`

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 ~ /79/ { sub(/79/, "hh", $2) }1' file
```

The problem with your attempt with `sed` is, the first `awk` filters only the 2nd row which upon substitution and re-direction produces a new file with only one row.

The one I have above, does a conditional substitution only on rows containing `$2` as `79` and do the substitution. For other rows that don't match the default print takes place `{..}1` to print out the line.

If you are looking for an even optimal way, you can avoid the redundant check before doing the substitution, just as below. Because `sub()` ignores doing any action on lines that do not contain the pattern, in which case the line is just simply printed.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } sub(/79/, "hh", $2) 1' file
```

To your additional question for starting with `b1` and length containing 6, you need to do

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 ~/^b1/ && length($2) == 6' file
```